# how to get dynamically created checkbox row value in gridview using javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, buttonclick

I have created a grid view with multiple dynamically generated check boxes but all of the check boxes have same id. How can I get row value of the selected check box?

here is my dyanamic control at gridvie rowdatabound event

```
protected void grdreport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int temp = e.Row.Cells.Count;

    temp--;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (temp >= 3)
        {
            strheadertext1 = grdreport.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Text;

            CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
            cb1.ID = "cb1";
            cb1.Text = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;

            e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(cb1);
        }
    }
}
```

and i  am getting value on button click

```
protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdreport.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("cb1");
        checkbox1.Checked = true;

        if (checkbox1.Checked)
        {
            string itemname = row.Cells[0].Text;
            string particular = row.Cells[1].Text;
            string qty = row.Cells[2].Text;
        }
    }
}
```

but when i am getting value it gives me first row value whenever i check second row checkbox

Comment: all of your checkboxes need to have unique IDs but you are hard coding the id of your checkbox

Comment: how can i  do that can u give me sample code

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul, aspnet will take care of unique id's since they are in a GridView control. They only have to be unique per row. In Client-Side they will have unique id's.

Answer (score 0):

You are hardcoding you ids. Do something like this:

```
//(or take the count of something else if this is not suitable)
int i = e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.count + 1;
CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
cb1.ID = "cb" + i;
```

To find the element in JavaScript:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkboxid");
```

Comment: No need. Controls can have the same ID inside a GridView, repeater etc. Client-Side they will still be unique per row.

Comment: @VDWWD Good point :) shows I need to read the requirements in more detail next time!

Answer (score 0):

You are looping all the rows, but never store values outside the loop, so the values will always be of the last checkbox checked.
Take a look at the following snippet and the values written to `Label1`. Those will be the values per row.

```
protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grdreport.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        GridViewRow row = grdreport.Rows[i];

        CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("cb1");
        if (checkbox1.Checked)
        {
            Label1.Text += string.Format("Row {0}: {1}<br>", i, row.Cells[1].Text);
        }
    }
}
```